# Host HTTP endpoint in Java

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration application which needs to be relatively resource efficient.  I want to expose a restful web service bound to localhost on a port > 1024.  Right now the application is running from the command line as `java -jar MyApp.jar`

Is there a way of hosting the webservice without firing up an application container like Tomcat?

**Update** In the spring app is a gateway in it that I want to expose as a webservice.

Comment: so right now you have a spring app, which you would like to expose as a web service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Instead of packaging your application as a WAR and deploy it in a Servlet Container, your Main Class application may start and configure a Servlet stack by its own.

Here are tutorials on how to embed and start Jetty from your Spring application:

- At [spring by examples](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/embedded-spring-web-services.html)
- At [eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty)
- At [codehaus docs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty)

The [following article](http://www.devx.com/java/Article/42315/1954) describes it in details too.

For restful service, you just follow [this documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html).